# Why does 1dp mean 3px and 2px at the same time on Android?

Tags: java, android, gridview, interface, screen

I use the following style for `GridView`:

```
<style name="CaldroidDefaultGridView">
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/caldroid_lighter_gray</item>
    <item name="android:horizontalSpacing">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:verticalSpacing">1dp</item>
```

And it shows 3px for padding and 2px for spacing on Pixel 2 emulator. If I implicitly specify 2px both for padding and spacing, then it shows 2px - so there is no extra pixel anywhere.

It happens in both directions - horizontal and vertical. For padding 1dp always means 3px. For spacing 1dp always means 2px.

Why does 1dp mean 3px and 2px at the same time on Android? How can I get the actual values then? Because I need to know them.

*P.S. I understand that it's hard to believe in the stated facts, so I can provide screenshots as the proof.*

Comment: I think screenshots would help identify the issue. :)

Comment: Could be a rounding artifact. On a Pixel 2 the screen density is 420 dpi (1dp=2.625px), which is between xhdpi (1dp=2px) and xxhdpi (1dp=3px). Obviously you have to size things with an integer number of pixels, and if you always round up it won't fit on the screen, so something's got to get rounded down. No idea how they choose what gets rounded down though.

Answer (score 4):

*dp* means density-independent pixels. Every smartphone has a different number that goes around 300dp - 420dpi if I don't remember bad. Anyway, your smartphone should have 1920x1080 as screen. So that's because 1dp could be 2-3px at the same time.

You can read more in the official developer android website.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: What exactly did you want to tell by your answer? Why does 1dp mean 3px and 2px at the same time? It happens in both directions - horizontal and vertical. For padding 1dp always means 3px. For spacing 1dp always means 2px. Why???

Comment: As you can see in the documentation the formula is
px = dp * (dpi / 160),
So, 
dp = px / (dpi/160).

So if your screen has 320dpi,
putting 2px you have
px / (dpi/160) = dp = 2 / (320 / 160) = 1dp.
Putting 3px you have
3/(320/160) = 1.5dp ~ 1dp.

It's math, in the linked documentation there is all

Comment: I don't ask about converting px to dp. Android converts 1dp to 3px and 2px at its random will. There is no math in this. So I want to find the cause of that **incorrect** behavior.

Comment: I don't think that your "answer" answers to anything related to my question. Please remove it.